# Best way to install multiple versions of Apache, PHP and MySQL on a single FreeBSD host

Tags: php, mysql, apache, web-hosting, freebsd

I want a test- and development-environment for web using Apache, PHP and MySQL. I need to be able to test a single web-application with multiple versions of PHP (5.2, 5.3, etc) and multiple versions of MySQL (5.0, 5.1, 5.5, etc). It shall be hosted on a FreeBSD server.

My idea is to compile each version into a directory structure and running them on separate portnumbers. For example:

```
opt/apache2.2-php5.2-mysql-5.0 
(httpd on port 8801, mysql on port 8802)
(directory contains each software, compiled and linked towards eachother)

opt/apache2.2-php5.3-mysql-5.1 
(httpd on port 8803, mysql on port 8804)
(and so on)
```

Any thoughts or suggestions of the best way to setup this type of environment?

**UPDATE:**
Question moved to serverfault:
https://serverfault.com/questions/145504/best-way-to-install-multiple-versions-of-apache-php-and-mysql-on-a-single-freebs

Comment: This question is more appropriate for serverfault or superuser.

Comment: @hemp: I'm thinking Arby's... er... serverfault.

Comment: check. posted on serverfault, will keep both posts updated with replies (if any...)

Comment: [Link to question on Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/145504/best-way-to-install-multiple-versions-of-apache-php-and-mysql-on-a-single-freebs)

Answer (score 1):

Try Wamp Server( this is what I am using)

http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php

or Xampp

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use FreeBSD's jail facility. See the /usr/ports/sysutils/ezjail port to make this quick and easy to get multiple jails going. Inside each jail, just install whatever ports you like, and test that way.